# Подскажите когда пытаюсь запустить build командой mvn clean install такая ошибка получается. Пытаюсь прикрутить allure к проекту

Tags: java, maven, allure, cucumber

Pom xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TrekerAutoTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.17.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/`введите сюда код`aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"</argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <allure-testng.version>2.6.0</allure-testng.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

</project>
```

консоль

```
user@Duser@DESKTOP-50V9J6O MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/uitestingsampleproject (allure)
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< org.example:TrekerAutoTest >---------------------
[INFO] Building TrekerAutoTest 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TrekerAutoTest ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\uitestingsampleproject\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TrekerAutoTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\uitestingsampleproject\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ TrekerAutoTest ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ TrekerAutoTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TrekerAutoTest ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\uitestingsampleproject\target\test-classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.894 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-15T12:15:08+05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project TrekerAutoTest: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 14 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

user@DESKTOP-50V9J6O MINGW64 ~/IdeaProjects/uitestingsampleproject (allure)
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главное в сообщении об ошибке это:

```
 Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 14
```

У вас в pom файле указана версия java - 14:

```
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
```

А в консоли доступна более старая версия. Проверьте командой в консоли `java -version`. Нужно установить (если не установлена) jdk как минимум версии 14, и добавить в `PATH` и установить `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: в консоле у меня $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.292.10.1 (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.292.10.1 (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
В path системном 
C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_292

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Отметил вопрос как решенный )